# Angular 9: not subscribing from other component?

Tags: angular, web-applications, observable, subscription, angular9

I have been trying to make an angular app that reads from submission data from a form and query into a database. I have been using observables and subscribe but it has not been working. I have been trying to console.log the observable data on form submission but it doesn't seem to change. Here's the code.

The service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {QueryData} from './QueryData';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ForSubmitService {
  private subject = new Subject<QueryData>();
  sendData(data: QueryData) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }
  getData(): Observable<QueryData> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The component that sends the data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
  providers: [ForSubmitService]
})

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private submitService: ForSubmitService
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      selectedHemisphere: '',
      selectedMonth: this.thisMonth,
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(formData) {
    const sendData = {northSelected: formData.selectedHemisphere === 'north',
      monthSelected: formData.selectedMonth};
    const data = new QueryData(sendData.northSelected, sendData.monthSelected);
    this.submitService.sendData(data); // This is the line sending the data
  }
```

The component receiving the data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fish-list',
  templateUrl: './fish-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fish-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ForSubmitService]
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  listData;
  formData;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private submitService: ForSubmitService ) {
    this.subscription = this.submitService.getData().subscribe(data => {console.log(data); this.formData = data; });
    // ^^^ This is the code that seems to not work
    console.log(this.formData);
    // console.log(this.subscription);
    // More database related code...
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, each component is seeing its own instance of the `ForSubmitService`. 
It's because of this line in your components:

```
 providers: [ForSubmitService]
```

If the `ForSubmitService` is global to your application, then change the `@Injectable` decorator to say so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

Read more about providers: [Angular - Providing dependencies in modules](https://angular.io/guide/providers)

Comment: Great! I wonder why I got a downvote? If the person who downvoted my answer would care to elaborate I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Joel I have similar problem. The Service is in library module. It is working fine from components inside library, but not working from application that imports library.